# Why raster.setPixels() is returning a grayscale image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

Here i'm trying to do a fastest method to save 3 matrix(R, G and B) into a BufferedImage.

I've found this method here at StackExchange, but it doesn't work for me because the image it's being saved  in a grayscale color.

If I'm doing something wrong or if there's a way of doing this faster than `bufferimage.setRGB()`, please help me. Thanks!

```java
public static BufferedImage array_rasterToBuffer(int[][] imgR,
         int[][]imgG, int[][] imgB) {

    final int width = imgR[0].length;
    final int height = imgR.length;
    int numBandas = 3;
    int[] pixels = new int[width*height*numBandas];
    int cont=0;
    System.out.println("max: "+width*height*3);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            for (int band = 0; band < numBandas; band++) {
                pixels[(((i*width)+j)*numBandas +band)] =Math.abs((  (imgR[i][j] & 0xff) >> 16 | (imgG[i][j] & 0xff) >> 8 | (imgB[i][j] & 0xff)));
                cont+=1;
            }
        }
    }


    BufferedImage bufferImg = new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    WritableRaster rast = (WritableRaster) bufferImg.getData(); 
    rast.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
    bufferImg.setData(rast);

    return bufferImg;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a faster approach, you need to get the "live" `WritableRaster` from the `BufferedImage` and set pixels in the "native" format of the image, which is "pixel packed" for `TYPE_INT_RGB`. This will save you multiple (at least two) array copies and some data conversion. It will also save you 2/3rds  of the memory used for the conversion, as we only need a single array component per pixel.

The below method should be quite a bit faster:

```
public static BufferedImage array_rasterToBuffer(int[][] imgR, int[][] imgG, int[][] imgB) {
    final int width = imgR[0].length;
    final int height = imgR.length;

    // The bands are "packed" for TYPE_INT_RGB Raster, 
    // so we need only one array component per pixel
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            // "Pack" RGB values to native TYPE_INT_RGB format
            // (NOTE: Do not use Math.abs on these values, and without alpha there won't be negative values)
            pixels[((y * width) + x)] = ((imgR[y][x] & 0xff) << 16 | (imgG[y][x] & 0xff) << 8 | (imgB[y][x] & 0xff));
        }
    }

    BufferedImage bufferImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // NOTE: getRaster rather than getData for "live" view
    WritableRaster rast = bufferImg.getRaster();

    // NOTE: setDataElements rather than setPixels to avoid conversion
    // This requires pixels to be in "native" packed RGB format (as above)
    rast.setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, pixels);

    // No need for setData as we were already working on the live data
    // thus saving at least two expensive array copies

    return bufferImg;
}

// Test method, displaying red/green/blue stripes
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] fooR = new int[99][99];
    int[][] fooG = new int[99][99];
    int[][] fooB = new int[99][99];

    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(fooR[i], 0xff);
        Arrays.fill(fooG[i + 33], 0xff);
        Arrays.fill(fooB[i + 66], 0xff);
    }

    BufferedImage image = array_rasterToBuffer(fooR, fooG, fooB);

    showIt(image);
}

// For demonstration only
private static void showIt(final BufferedImage image) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("JPEGTest");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
            scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            frame.add(scroll);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

It is possible to optimize this further, if you don't need a "managed" (possible hardware accelerated for display) image. The trick is to create the image directly "around" your `pixels` array, thus saving one more array allocation and array copy in `setDataElements`. The downside is that in some cases the image will be a little slower to draw onto the screen. This is mainly a concern for games or smooth animations though.

Replace the lines from `BufferedImage bufferImg = new BufferedImage...` until the `return` statement, with the following code:

```
DataBufferInt buffer = new DataBufferInt(pixels, pixels.length);

int[] bandMasks = {0xFF0000, 0xFF00, 0xFF}; // RGB (no alpha)
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, width, height, width, bandMasks, null);

ColorModel cm = new DirectColorModel(32,
        0x00ff0000,       // Red
        0x0000ff00,       // Green
        0x000000ff,       // Blue
        0x00000000        // No Alpha
);
BufferedImage bufferImg = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

PS: Note that I also changed the shifts inside the x/y loop, from right to left shifts. Might have been just a minor typo. :-)

Comment: HaraldK, i'm gonna test this and give you a feedback.
Thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It works really good and faster than the other code of this question, precisely 7,1% in my methods. @haraldK, thank you so much!

Comment: @RochaRF Good. I was expecting more than 7% difference, but well... 7% is still something. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting grey because the expression

```
Math.abs((  (imgR[i][j] & 0xff) >> 16 | (imgG[i][j] & 0xff) >> 8 | (imgB[i][j] & 0xff)));
```

does not depend on `band`, so your rgb values are all the same.

The expression looks dodgy anyway because you normally use the left shift operator `<<` when packing rgb values into a single `int`.

I don't know for sure, as I'm not familiar with the classes you are using, but I'm guessing something like this might work

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        pixels[(((i*width)+j)*numBandas)]     = imgR[i][j] & 0xFF;
        pixels[(((i*width)+j)*numBandas + 1)] = imgG[i][j] & 0xFF;
        pixels[(((i*width)+j)*numBandas + 2)] = imgB[i][j] & 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use the same expression and only change to << operator, it continues grayscale.
How should i do it then? Put three 2d arrays into on 1d array ?

Comment: @user5530314 I'm assuming the three bands are red, green and blue. Is this right?

Comment: @user5530314 I've had a go, but I'm not really sure if it will work.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it work's and solved my problem!!!
However, this method it's not faster than the one i usually use. I'll search for a faster way to set three 2d array into a buffereimage.

Comment: @user5530314 No problem. The update should be slightly faster, but I don't know how to do it most efficiently - you'd probably need native code. It's a problem I've run into too.

Comment: @user5530314, PaulBoddington: See my answer below for a faster version, and an explanation of why it's faster.